# jquery ajax post request is successive but still not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to do a simple ajax post request to another page, with the same code I've another time, but this time it does not seem to work, even though the alert I put at success works. The variables do not seem to transfer, but even disregarding the variables and used putting a simple request on the other page does not seem to help. This is my code now:

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('.sortable').sortable({
            stop:function()
            {
                var ids = '';
                $('.sortable div').each(function(){
                    id = $(this).attr('id');
                    if(ids == '')
                    {
                        ids = id;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ids = ids+','+id;
                    }

                }),
                $.ajax({
                    url:'<?php $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]. "inhoud/dashboard/change_order.php"?>',
                    data:{ids: ids, user_id: '<?php echo $user_id; ?>'},
                    type:'POST',
                    success: alert('yay')
                });
            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

Everything in the script seems to work. The ids array fills exactly how it is supposed to be, and also the user_id is rightly defined. I have tried every way to link to the document, but every way seems to fail. What is supposed to happen is that the call to the other page gets made, where the data given in the post requested is handled, but even though almost exactly the same code works in multiple other scenarios, this time it seems to fail.

Comment: This `success: alert('yay')` doesn't do what you think. It will alert yay as soon as the request fires, not once it succeeds. You want `success: () => alert('yay')`

Comment: What happens instead? Is this a JS problem, or a PHP problem?

Comment: Are you sure you're defining the `url` correctly? Using `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` might equal something like `/var/www/mysite.com/`, which is not a valid link for your AJAX. You might be looking for `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`, which outputs `mysite.com`. Or you might remove that altogether, and just go with `url: "inhoud/dashboard/change_order.php"`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a function inside the success
like this ->

`success: function(){ alert('yay'); // do something }`

Comment: One small suggestion - using `success: function(data) { alert('yay); // do something with data}` might be better, if you plan on doing something with the data received from the AJAX. For example, the AJAX might have completed, and `success` might've been triggered, but the response was something along the lines of `{'error' : true, 'message' : 'failed to insert data into database'}`.

Comment: @FiddlingAway For that need to add a parameter, and after that write your logic  
You are right
Thank you